# Limit of $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: limits

Given a function
$$ f\left(x{,}\ y{,}\ z\right)=\frac{\alpha_1x+\alpha_2y+\alpha_3z}{\beta_1x+\beta_2y+\beta_3z},$$
does the limit $$ \lim_{\left(x{,}\ y{,}\ z\right)\rightarrow\left(0{,}\ 0{,}\ 0\right)}f\left(x{,}\ y{,}\ z\right) $$ exist?

So far I have solved for one case, that if all the coefficients $$ \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3,  \beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3 $$are non-zero, then the limit exists, if vectors $$\left(\alpha_1{,}\ \alpha_2{,}\ \alpha_3\right)\ \mathrm{and}\ \left(\beta_1{,}\ \beta_2{,}\ \beta_3\right) $$  are linearly dependent.

What about other cases, if I can't assume that all coefficients are non-zero? I may however assume, that there exists at least one non-zero coefficient β (for the the divisor not to be equal to zero) , and in this particular case which I am interested in, that there exists at least one non-zero coefficient α.

Comment: The limit of $f$ as $(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)$ does not exist. Take $(x,0,0)\to(0,0,0)$, then $(0,y,0)\to(0,0,0)$ and you get different answers. By the definition of limit, it should not matter how the point $(0,0,0)$ is approached.

Comment: @Chrystomath (x,0,0) -> (0,0,0); what about if beta1 is zero?

Comment: The only way it converges is if $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)=\lambda(\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3)$.

Comment: @Chrystomath Okay, thank you! Can you please give some more precise justification to that argument?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(x,y,z)$ converges to some number $\lambda$ as $(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)$.

Then taking $y=0=z$ and $x\to0$, we get $$\lambda=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\alpha_1x}{\beta_1x}=\frac{\alpha_1}{\beta_1}$$

Similarly, taking $y\to0$ and $z\to0$ keeping the other coordinates zero, we get $$\lambda=\frac{\alpha_2}{\beta_2}=\frac{\alpha_3}{\beta_3}$$

Hence $\alpha_i=\lambda\beta_i$.

Conversely, if $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)=\lambda(\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3)$ then $f(x,y,z)=\lambda$ is constant, so it obviously converges as $(x,y,z)\to0$.